# Here is the question: about python "Display numbers divisible by 5 from a list" . I wrote this answer, but something is not right

Tags: python

```
def five (numberlist):
    print("Given list is", numberlist)
    for num in numberlist:
        if num % 5 == 0:
            print(num)

lisst = [10, 26, 33, 45, 55]
print("Divisible by 5", five(lisst))
```

Output is:

```
Given list is [10, 26, 33, 45, 55]
10
45
55
Divisible by 5 None
```

It gave me the answer but I don't want to see "None". Why do you think "None" appears?

Comment: How many `print` statements do you have? What do you expect each to output and why?

Comment: 2. Do you think second "print" is useless?

Comment: You have *three* `print` statements. The third is trying to print the return value of `five`. `five` doesn't `return` anything.

Comment: Just run this *five()* as this way - ```five(L)```.   Because the default behavior of function (w/o return) is - `None`.  As ^^^ pointed out.